# how to use SVM in Java about Android application

Tags: java, svm

[This image about value of algae after calculate shape measures and other. I want to send this value to SVM.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlEWn.png)

I create a my project about android application classification of algae. I use library opencv after I get value from shape measures and texture i want to send value to SVM train for test and return name of class algae to UI. How should i start it.

** If illegally asking for information, please apologize here. **

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You should have a look at the documentation and search for some examples like [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/188316/training-and-prediction-svm-java/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Bank Ky. We recommend that you come with questions about things that you've already tried to solve on your own. Can you demonstrate something specific that you're confused about or show any code you've already attempted to implement?

Comment: @GrantNoe yes I try it but I'm still a little confused about the code. However thank you for you're comment

Comment: It's okay to be confused. Why don't you post some of the code that you've attempted here so that we can help you with a more specific issue? The problem is that it's not this site's objective to do all of the coding for you, so we need something to go off of.

Comment: @GrantNoe Now I understand something of svm and I try it. if i problem I will ask this site again. Thank you so much